# PHP: xpath or prev() or for loop?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm banging my head against the wall here. I'm trying to loop through an XML file and when a certain criteria is met, add a node to the previous element.

I've tried using the prev() command but my research indicates that's the wrong approach anyway. I've tried the xpath command but I can't get it to work.

My XML looks like this:

```
<ArrayOfProductFeedEntity>

    <ProductFeedEntity>
        <StockNo>123</StockNo>
        <MoreNodes>XXX</MoreNodes>
        <MoreNodes>XXX</MoreNodes>
    </ProductFeedEntity>

    <ProductFeedEntity>
        <StockNo>456</StockNo>
        <MoreNodes>XXX</MoreNodes>
        <MoreNodes>XXX</MoreNodes>
    </ProductFeedEntity>

    <ProductFeedEntity>
        <StockNo>456-A</StockNo>
        <MoreNodes>XXX</MoreNodes>
        <MoreNodes>XXX</MoreNodes>
    </ProductFeedEntity>

    <ProductFeedEntity>
        <StockNo>789</StockNo>
        <MoreNodes>XXX</MoreNodes>
        <MoreNodes>XXX</MoreNodes>
    </ProductFeedEntity>
</ArrayOfProductFeedEntity>
```

When I reach 456-A I want to back up to just 456 and add the following nodes. I'm using a foreach to loop through the $xml variable.

```
$p = $xml->xpath("/ArrayOfProductFeedEntity/ProductFeedEntity[StockNo=$stock]");
$size = $p->addChild("Options")->addChild("Size");
$size->addChild("Name","Size");
$size->addChild("Value", $stock);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always need a loop, SimpleXMLElement::xpath() returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects. Even if the expression returns only one or none.

But what you asked can be done directly in the initial XPath expression.

Your expression:

`/ArrayOfProductFeedEntity/ProductFeedEntity[StockNo='456-A']`

You're executing that expression on the `ArrayOfProductFeedEntity` element node, so the expression can be simplified to:

`ProductFeedEntity[StockNo='456-A']`

Now starting with that node you can get its preceding siblings:

`ProductFeedEntity[StockNo='456-A']/preceding-sibling::*`

and limit it to the first (nearest):

`ProductFeedEntity[StockNo='456-A']/preceding-sibling::*[1]`

Full example:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$expression = "ProductFeedEntity[StockNo='456-A']/preceding-sibling::*[1]";
foreach ($xml->xpath($expression) as $p) {
  $size = $p->addChild("Options")->addChild("Size");
  $size->addChild("Name","Size");
  $size->addChild("Value", $stock);
}
echo $xml->asXml();
```